# US national debt clock

Tags: flash

I repair computers. I've never done any programming, but I've been asked by a customer to set up a computer in his store that does nothing but display the US national debt clock in real time. I found the clock in an SWF format. It says it will allow one to change the text at the top and bottom, which I'd like to do for for him by making the top a title bar and the bottom would hold his store name. The problem is, I don't have the first clue how to do this. Here's the address:

http://www.oddhammer.com/tutorials/debt_clock/

I want to have as large as possible " National Debt in Real Time" in the top banner, and "Courtesy of DealMart" in the bottom. Can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: It's really just cut and paste. If you read the page carefully, then do a 'view source' to find where he added "hello" and "world", it'll show you. Then just put the SWF in a directory, open up a full screen web page with just that on it, and let it run.

Comment: This is really too localized for Stack Overflow, however I believe you've got the advice that you need.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> "iexplore http://www.usdebtclock.org/" <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As that page says, you can configure the variables in the `FlashVars` parameter:

```
<noscript><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0" width="340" height="155">
<param name="movie" value="US_debt_clock_dynamic.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="topString=National Debt in Real Time&bottomString=Courtesy of DealMart" />
<embed src="US_debt_clock_dynamic.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="340" height="155" FlashVars="topString=Hello&bottomString=World"></embed>
</object></noscript>
```

You'd better ask the author whether you can display his work re-branded, without attribution, in a public, commercial environment.